# Which meaning of 'express' is used here?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

In this [article](https://www.lawteryx.com/knowledge-center/criminal-law/illegal-internet-searches/), there is such a paragraph:

> Although the “dark web” is a mystery to some, it does exist and is the criminal underworld of the internet. Not only can you find child pornography for sale, but you can also hire an assassin. Obviously, hiring an assassin to kill someone is illegal. This is precisely why you must **express caution** when performing such searches. Stay away from the dark web so that your innocent search for a crime novel or video game will keep you off a watchlist.

I think 'express caution' here means 'be cautious', but which meaning of 'express' is used here? The following is a list of the meaning of 'express' as a verb given by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/express), none of which seems to fit the above use to me.

> - 1 a: to represent in words : STATE
>
>   - b: to make known the opinions or feelings of (oneself)
>   - c: to give expression to the artistic or creative impulses or abilities of (oneself)
>   - d: to give or convey a true impression of : SHOW, REFLECT
>   - e: to represent by a sign or symbol : SYMBOLIZE
>   - f: DELINEATE, DEPICT
> - 2: to send by express
> - 3 a: to force out (something, such as the juice of a fruit) by pressure
>
>   - b: to subject to pressure so as to extract something
> - 4: to cause (a gene) to manifest its effects in the phenotype
>
>   - also : to manifest or produce (a character, molecule, or effect) by a genetic process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence uses the verb 'express' wrongly. A better verb would be 'use'. I think possibly the writer was thinking of 'employ', which is a grander word meaning the same thing.

> Obviously, hiring an assassin to kill someone is illegal. This is
> precisely why you must **use caution** when performing such searches.